# ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_DOWN for OnTouchListener returning false

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, touch-event, motionevent, android-touch-event

I have implemented an `OnTouchListener` in Android 5.1 which disables touch input and only allows stylus input (or any other input than touch) in the following way:

```
View.OnTouchListener touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if ((event.getToolType(0) == MotionEvent.TOOL_TYPE_FINGER)) {
            // Touch input
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

This works great. Returning true does not pass the touch event to underlying activity, that is what I want.

According to what I have read, returning false is passing the event to underlying activity but only ACTION_DOWN should be processed and ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP should no more be processed (because somehow the chain is stopped after ACTION_DOWN when returning false). In my case ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP are still called and processed by the OnTouchListener although I'm returning false.

Why is this the case? I want to have also the ACTION_UP and ACTION_MOVE events, that is not the problem but I don't understand the behavior according to what I have read.